# In my calculator GUI with python tkinter, the 'Error' message in the entry widget is not automatically removing when i am writing the expression again

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a simple calculator GUI in Python using `tkinter` and everything is working perfectly.
I have added `+`, `-`, `/` and `*` functionalities only.
I have added a functionality that if someone types something that can't be evaluated, say `6w+8`, then it shows an `Error` message in the `Entry` widget.
I want that `Error` message to disappear automatically when I start typing again from keyboard or from the buttons I've made in the GUI (even if I move the insertion cursor when `Error` message shows and then type).
It is disappearing when I press my GUI buttons and the text of that button appearing on the screen that is what I want. But the problem is that the `Error` message is not disappearing if I press a key of the keyboard (not GUI buttons).
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Calculator')
root.geometry('790x680+350+7')


def calc_operation(event):
    if entered_data.get() == 'Error':
        input_screen.delete(0, END)

    pressed_button_value = event.widget.cget('text')
    cursor_index = input_screen.index(INSERT)
    input_screen.insert(cursor_index, pressed_button_value)


def result(event=None):
    final_expression = ''
    for character in entered_data.get():
        if character.lower() == 'x':
            character = '*'

        elif character == '÷':
            character = '/'

        final_expression += character

    # Error handling
    try:
        answer = eval(final_expression)
        if answer.__ceil__() == answer:
            answer = int(answer)
        entered_data.set(answer)
        input_screen.icursor(len(entered_data.get()))

    except:
        if entered_data.get() == '':
            entered_data.set('')

        else:
            entered_data.set('Error')
            input_screen.icursor(len(entered_data.get()))


def clear(event=None):
    input_screen.delete(0, END)


def backspace():
    cursor_index = input_screen.index(INSERT)

    if cursor_index == 0:
        pass
    else:
        input_screen.delete(cursor_index-1)


# Binding keyboard buttons
root.bind('<Return>', result)
root.bind('<Delete>', clear)


# Input screen
entered_data = StringVar()

input_screen = Entry(root, font='helvetica 45', bd=4, relief=SUNKEN, textvariable=entered_data, justify=RIGHT)
input_screen.pack(pady=40, padx=20, fill=X)
input_screen.focus()


# Buttons for the numbers
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady=50)

button7 = Button(frame, text='7', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button7.grid()
button7.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button8 = Button(frame, text='8', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button8.grid(row=0, column=1)
button8.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button9 = Button(frame, text='9', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button9.grid(row=0, column=2)
button9.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button4 = Button(frame, text='4', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
button4.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button5 = Button(frame, text='5', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
button5.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button6 = Button(frame, text='6', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
button6.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button1 = Button(frame, text='1', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
button1.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button2 = Button(frame, text='2', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button2.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button3 = Button(frame, text='3', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button3.grid(row=2, column=2)
button3.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

button0 = Button(frame, text='0', font='helvetica 34', relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='green')
button0.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
button0.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)


# Buttons for operations
division_button = Button(frame, text='÷', font='helvetica 34', width=7, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')        
division_button.grid(row=0, column=3)
division_button.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

multiplication_button = Button(frame, text='x', font='helvetica 22 bold', relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
multiplication_button.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=NSEW)
multiplication_button.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

addition_button = Button(frame, text='+', font='helvetica 34', width=7, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
addition_button.grid(row=2, column=3)
addition_button.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

subtraction_button = Button(frame, text='-', font='helvetica 34', width=7, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
subtraction_button.grid(row=3, column=3)
subtraction_button.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)


# Buttons for the symbols
decimal_button = Button(frame, text='.', font='helvetica 34', width=4, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
decimal_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
decimal_button.bind('<Button-1>', calc_operation)

backspace_button = Button(frame, text='←', font='helvetica 34', width=7, command=backspace, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
backspace_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

clear_button = Button(frame, text='Clear', font='helvetica 19 bold', command=clear, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
clear_button.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

equal_button = Button(frame, text='=', font='helvetica 34', width=7, command=result, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
equal_button.grid(row=2, column=4)

exit_button = Button(frame, text='Exit', font='helvetica 19 bold', command=root.destroy, relief=RAISED, bd=4, bg='red', fg='white')
exit_button.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

root.mainloop()
```

I also tried to bind the keys. Here is what I did:

```
def calc_operation2(event):
    cursor_index = input_screen.index(INSERT)
    input_screen.delete(cursor_index-1)

    if entered_data.get() == 'Error':
        input_screen.delete(0, END)

    input_screen.insert(cursor_index, event.char)


root.bind('<Key>', calc_operation2)
```

and it is working. But it creates a new problem that when I press `backspace` key, it removed the `Error` message and displaying a weird rectangle shape in `Entry` widget.
Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: bind that entry to any keypress and then delete(0, 'end')

Answer (score 0):

Does this help You solve the issue (You still have to keep the other check in the calc_func):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.insert(0, 'Error')
entry.bind('<Key>', lambda x: entry.delete(0, 'end') if entry.get() == 'Error' else None)

root.mainloop()
```

here is another way:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry


def check(event):
    if event.widget.get() == 'Error':
        event.widget.delete(0, 'end')


root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.insert(0, 'Error')
entry.bind('<Key>', check)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it worked, i replaced my `calc_operation2() ` function with your `check()` function (the second way you advised) and bind the keys with Entry(not the root). Could you please explain me the 2 lines of code in your `check()` function?

Comment: @Pythoneer the first line is the if statement and in that statement code calls function `get()` from `event.widget` which is the widget that triggered the event, in this case the `entry`so basically it is the same as `entry.get()` except You could bind this to multiple widget instances without specifying their variable name. and this `.get()` function gets the current entry and then evaluates if it equals 'Error'

Comment: and if it does it again uses the `event.widget` which is the same widget that triggered the event and in this case `entry` so could again be written as `entry.delete()` and delete method deletes string from the widget in the specified range so in this case from including 0 - the first character until the 'end' - including the last character

Comment: But when a key was pressed say `4` then it was becoming `Error4`(say, if the cursor was at the end) hence i was not able to compare it with `Error` in the if statement, as after pressing a key it became `Error + the key pressed` according to the cursor position. So in the function `calc_operation2()` i was first taking the cursor's current position in order to delete `4` then deleted `4`. After that the text in `entry` would be 'Error' so i was using if statement and removing the message and then again putting `4` by using event.char.

Comment: Wait so does it like work? or not? also as I mentioned You should have kept Your calc function as is and just added a bind and defined another function since calc function already was deleting text in entry and seemed to work fine

Comment: But you are checking only for `Error` in the if statement and it worked. My question is whenever a key is pressed it always appears in the entry so how can we compare it with only `Error` as it is `Error + the key pressed(added to `Error` according to cursor position). Means first the text of the key appears in `entry` and then the function bound to the entry gets executed.

Comment: Yes, but it sort of seems to detect a key press then check and then put the character at least for me, I mean I can even type in "Error" myself and as soon as I press the key it seems to start appearing and then the error part gets deleted and the key I was pressing appears at the start

Comment: I guess it first detects a keypress since it is bound to do so and then since it should be the next step it executes the function so yeah it probably registers what key was pressed but then it triggers event and is only displayed after executing the bound function.

Comment: @Pythoneer but at the end does it work or not? I am a bit confused. Also to mention it first reaches mainloop before executing that .delete function; can be tested with sleep that when it sleeps the error is still in entry and then after sleeping it deletes it and places the typed character in it (with sleep You can also see that it (`.bind()`) first reaches mainloop and thus executes the script so the key is put in the entry last)

Comment: That it what i was asking. Now it is very much clear. Thanks a lot for such a great explaination sir. And yes my program is working very well now.